# If a user reinstalls and app on their device after deleting it, does this count as another download?

Tags: ios, download, reinstall

If someone installs your IOS Apple App on their apple device, then deletes it and reinstalls it, does this count as 2 downloads in your itunes downloads statistics counter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, reinstalling or updating an app still counts as one download.

-Edit:
"By default, updates and previous purchase downloads are excluded"~ from iTunes connect

Comment: Is it device dependent or account dependent? suppose I have 2 device and I use one account to install an application on both of the device. Will that count as 2 download or one?

Comment: It's based on the account.

Comment: @rebello95 Can you indicate me to any authenticated source that state the same. I will be really thankful.

Comment: I just found where that was displayed. It is displayed in a text box once you click on the info button by the units text in the sales report.